# How to Show Png Images in Webglrenderer of three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three.js r84 to render a globe with multiple points connected with flights. 
i want to use png images for the points. but texture loader adds the background color to that image. Here is my code to add the point to scene.

```
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('static/assets/images/point.jpg'),
    size: 16,
    sizeAttenuation: false
});
return pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
```

Comment: Try to add `alphaTest: 0.5, transparent: true` to parameters of the `PointsMaterial`. And have a look at [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_billboards) example.

Comment: Thanku Boss @prisoner849